# Regex for disallowing commas

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to disallow commas in a string entered into a textbox. Here is what I have so far:

```
[RegularExpression (@"?[^,]*$",
        ErrorMessage = "Commas are not allowed in the subtask title. Please remove any and try again")]
```

This is probably my 5th or 6th attempt, nothing so far has worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you start your regex with a '?'?

Comment: It was used in another example I found here on Stack Overflow. I really don't know what I'm doing here, I'm basically willing to try anything.

Comment: @Daniel do your homework then if you have no idea what you are doing :)

Comment: @AndreasMüller kind of hard to do when Visual Studio doesn't follow common regex syntax, and doesn't explain it's bastardized version very well.

Comment: @Daniel It actually does. Your regex was wrong, it had nothing to do with VisualStudio. The correct regex is nothing VS specific.

Comment: FWIW Regex is like (and requires) finesse- I always hack-n-slash through it... For some people it is just Greek- There are some useful guides online and then there are a few VS snap-ins. It's kind of something you have to play with a lot to have down well.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try changing your regex to:

```
"^[^,]+$"
```

Let's say we're matching against `"Hello, world"`

The first `^` asserts that we're at the beginning of the string. Next `[^,]` is a character class which means "Any character except `,`." `+` next to something means "Match this one or more times." Finally, `$` asserts that we're now at the end of the string.

So, this regular expression means "At the start of the string (`^`), match any character that's not a comma (`[^,]`) one or more times (`+`) until we reach the end of the string (`$`).

This regular expression will fail on `"Hello, world"` - everything will be fine for `H`, `e`, `l`, `l`, and `o`, until we reach the comma - at which point the character class fails to match "not a comma".

For some great tutorials about regular expressions, you should read up on http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: So what does the * do? In @avinashRaj response, he used the * character which did exactly what I wanted. What's the difference between that and +?

Comment: @Daniel * is 0 or more, + means at least 1

Comment: `*` means 0 or more times - or in other words, "this is optional". For example, if you wanted to match "http" and "https" and didn't care which it is as long as both match, you would use `"https?"` ("match `h`, match `t`, match `t`, match `p`, and match `s` if it's there but don't worry if it's not")

Comment: So why does the * work at all? If it is 0 or more, shouldn't it be considering the whole string invalid no matter what the input is?

Comment: So it seems that the + is actually the correct way to accomplish this then? The * could have some unintended consequences?

Comment: The `*` works because `[^,]*` means "Match anything that's not a comma 0 or more times" - so, because we have `^` and `$` matching the start and end of the string, we need everything between the start and end of the string to be anything that's not a comma.
The only literal difference, in this case, is that `*` will allow an empty string, whereas `+` demands that it's at least one character long.